# Java load ResourceBundle inside WAR that contains several jar with their ResourceBundle

Tags: java, maven, internationalization, resourcebundle

I have a java project called API, it has its own ResourceBundle, because it know the language of the user, and the response is written according to its language. 
The tests are working fine, I see the messages correctly written.

When I want to use the jar of the API project inside another project, lets call it REST_API, it doesn't find any key from API.

The REST_API has it's own language keys, so the final bundle files should have a merge of the bundles. Right?

I'm using maven to build the jar, wars, etc. 
Is there any maven plugin that scan the projects, and merge resource bundle files in order to make it work?

Or should I implement it in a different way?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Resources in API project are in:

```
   src/main/resources/ApplicationMessages_en.properties 
   src/main/resources/ApplicationMessages_es.properties
```

The following is an example of how I load the bundles:

```
   private static final String DEFAULT_LANG = "en";
   private static final Locale DEFAULT_LOCALE = new Locale(DEFAULT_LANG);
   private static final ResourceBundle DEFAULT_TRANSL = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ApplicationMessages", DEFAULT_LOCALE, new UTF8Control());
```

Comment: The resources should be loaded via classpath so this shouldn't be problem ? If you use the API project insider another project do you have a correct dependency ? How does you project look like ? maven pom's ?

Comment: I just have a mvn dependency in the POM file. Like so: `<dependency>
   <groupId>grId</groupId>
   <artifactId>prAPI</artifactId>
   <version>${pr.version}</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: If you use the same name for both bundles, then no, they won't be merged. The first one found in the classpath will be used. Just as for classes. A resource bundle should be in a package, just like classes.

Comment: Ok, Nizet. I'll try that. The package of the bundle is in the src/main/resources folder, right?

Comment: Nizet, that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Resource files are placed in a package inside resource folder:

```
src/main/resources/my.package.api.lang.ApplicationMessages_en.properties
src/main/resources/my.package.api.lang.ApplicationMessages_es.properties
```

And in the REST API project:

```
src/main/resources/my.package.api.rest.lang.ApplicationMessages_en.properties
src/main/resources/my.package.api.rest.lang.ApplicationMessages_es.properties
```

To load those files:

```
// lang = "es" || "en"
// bundleName = "my.package.api.lang.ApplicationMessages"
// bundleName = "my.package.api.rest.lang.ApplicationMessages"
final Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
ResourceBundle translator = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleName, locale);
```

thanks!